# How to decode/understand the math behind ACF and PACF?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, acf-pacf

For the past month I have been trying to understand the math behind the autocorrelation function and partial autocorrelation function for time-series project I have been working on. However, I am only able to find loads of articles which answer questions like *How you can generate ACF & PACF* plot in Python or in R, *How to understand ACF and PACF plot?* or *How to obtain p and q values from ACF or PACF plot?* Nowhere I am able to find something which tells me the exact math behind them!

I am looking for something that derives this comprehensively enough, in hopes of trying to replicate derivation myself(am a computer science graduate). Can anyone help me out with the same? Any resource would do! Or maybe list down all the steps so that I can try researching in pieces.

Comment: This paper on the [characterization of the pacf](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176342881) might be of some help to you.

Comment: Thank you @Stochastic for the resource. Will definitely check this out.

Comment: You will find all the math in the Brockwell & Davis book "Introduction to Time Series and Forecasting"

Answer (score -2):

The lectures provided [here](https://henrikmadsen.org/books/time-series-analysis/), based on the book Time Series Analysis are comprehensive. They might require a bit of background in control theory though.

Comment: Thank you @Akylas, will check the resource out! The lectures seem to be comprehensive. Will try and add an answer here, if I am able to churn up any of the derivations!